# Simple Erlang Watcher to detect new/changes file in directory

Tags: erlang, file-watcher

Is there any simple **WATCHER** in **Erlang** that will **notify** me if there any addition/changes in a file of the folder. The frequency of changes in files of the folder will be rare.

I being newbie, link & description with an answer will be helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/synrc/fs/). Also check out this [tutorial](http://hostiledeveloper.com/2016/02/24/hey-watch-it-or-how-to-monitor-files-in-elixir.html) which is in Elixir but should give you the general idea.